# adding multiple properties to object in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think my question is easy but I dont understand why my solution doesnt work :(
I'm trying to add to a new object some long properties using foreach loop but I'm getting the whole time error. 
Could someone please help me?

```
let i = 0;
const obj = {};
for (const item of read) {
  console.log(item.name);
  console.log(item.imageURL);
  obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';
  console.log(item.name);
  if (item.imageURL) {
    obj['hits']['hits'][i]['_source.ActiveChannelReleases'][0]['ImageExports'][0]['Resolutions'][0]['Url'] =getServerURL()+item.imageURL;
  } else {
    obj['hits']['hits'][i]['_source.ActiveChannelReleases'][0]['ImageExports'][0]['Resolutions'][0]['Url'] ='https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/kitchen-glyph-black/2048/4834_-_Cookbook-512.png';
  }
  console.log(item.imageURL);
  i++;
}
```

I have an response and I want to mock it with my data

I wish to have for example an object that I can fill with data:

```
class ResponseController {
  constructor() {
    this.response = {
      'hits': {
        'hits': [{'_source.ActiveChannelReleases': [{'ImageExports': ['Resolutions']}],

        }],
      },
    };
  }
}
module.exports = ResponseController;
```

Will it work if I write

```
obj = new ResponseController();
```

and then I can easily add variables from the looo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this is a madness :).

**Why is not working?**

`const obj = {};`

you cannot do this `obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';` due to `obj['hist']` does not exists.

You need to do:

`obj['hits'] = {}`

and then `obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';`

And the same for the rest...

I cannot understand what do you want to do here:

`obj['hits']['hits'][i]['_source.ActiveChannelReleases'][0]['ImageExports'][0]['Resolutions'][0]['Url']`

But follow what I said before, you need to create each step the value you want. I can assume that you want an array in ´hits`...

Comment: thank you :) would it better to initialise obj with that structure? How to do it? that after that I can feel obj easily?

Comment: @AnnaK if you can explain what do you want to do, maybe I can help you to find a better solution.

Comment: I edited my question. Could you please take a look?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're defining `obj` to be an object, and then are trying to add stuff into `obj.hits` without defining that as an object

```
const obj = {};
obj['hits'] = {}
obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';
```