# How to create multiple object properties with a loop

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I'm learning JavaScrit/node.JS and I made the code below, which checks for how many vehicles a player has stored in the database once he joins the server and spawns all them. The problem is that it only works for one vehicle right now (personalVehicles gets overwritten, I belive)

```
mp.events.add("playerReady", (player) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, con) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log()
            con.query("SELECT vehicleID, vehicleModel, vehicleSpawnX, vehicleSpawnY, vehicleSpawnZ FROM vehicles WHERE vehicleType = ? AND vehicleOwner = ?", ["players", player.playerID], function (err, result) {
                if (err) console.log(err)
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    vehicleModel = result[i].vehicleModel
                    player.personalVehicles = mp.vehicles.new(parseInt(vehicleModel), new mp.Vector3(result[i].vehicleSpawnX, result[i].vehicleSpawnY, result[i].vehicleSpawnZ))
                }
            });
        con.release()
    });
});
```

I've tried switching `player.personalVehicles` with`player.personalVehicles.vehicle[i]`, `player.personalVehicles.vehicle` and `player.personalVehicles.[i]`, but none of them worked.

I pretend to do something like this automatically:

```
player = {
      personalVehicles = {
               vehicle1 = xxxxxxx
               vehicle2 = xxxxxxx
               vehicle3 = xxxxxxx
               and so on
                          }
}
```

I know it only works for one vehicle because when I try to destroy the player's vehicles once he leaves only one vehicle gets destroy (the last one in the database).

Thanks.

Comment: [*Here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57539610/adding-multiple-properties-to-object-in-a-loop) you might find a probable answer for your question.

Comment: So, I add ```player.personalVehicles = {}``` before the loop, that's it?

Answer (score 0):

`const obj = {};`

you cannot do this `obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';` due to `obj['hist']` does not exists.

You need to do:

`obj['hits'] = {}`

and then  `obj['hits']['hits'] ='whyDosntWork';`

And the same for the rest...

I cannot understand what do you want to do here:

`obj['hits']['hits'][i]['_source.ActiveChannelReleases'][0]['ImageExports'][0]['Resolutions'][0]['Url']`

But follow what I said before, you need to create each step the value you want. I can assume that you want an array in ´hits`